# How to plot a simple function in python?

Tags: python, numpy, plot, matplotlib

I have to implement a perceptron neural network in python.

For each training epoch (iterations over the training set), I record the number of errors in the predictions. I have to plot the errors as a function of epochs:

i.e.:

```
1 epoch -> 40 errors
2 epoch -> 30 errors
3 epoch -> 22 errors
...
```

I was thinking of making the x axis the epoch number and the y axis the error number, then I plot a few data points and connect the dots with a continuous line. How can I do that?

Comment: Well, you have matplotlib tagged so why not start by looking into that?

Comment: @Casey so how would you do this with matplotlib?

Comment: Take a look at the [matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html) for examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pylab
pylab.plot(epochs, errors)
pylab.show()
```